# Is there a library for encryption/decryption in EOS?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code

I want to perform some encryption on a given message, so I am wondering if there is a library that I can use in EOS? And I have checked the post  [Cryptographic Operations in Smart Contracts?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/153/cryptographic-operations-in-smart-contracts), but the links in that post have expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ***cryptoapi*** at https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.5.0/group__crypto.html.